# excel latest n rows

Tags: excel, excel-formula, worksheet-function

I'm trying to retrieve the values of the latest 6 rows that are not blank. As you can see in the picture, I would get all values from 54 to 39, but if the two blank cells had numbers, then counting would stop at 45.

Visullay

[image]

On an other tab I have an `INDEX` function that attempts to grab these numbers but only works for the first value found. 
This for example gives `54`, the first value.  `=INDEX(Database!b5:b50,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX((Database!b5:b50<>0),0),0))`

I would like to extend this and use it to call any `nth` value, preferably the top 6. So every time I update the dates and add new value, the top 6 cells auto update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost there. Just add a +n to the last argument of the outer INDEX formula. For example, this gets the next item, 51:

```
=INDEX(database!B5:B50,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX((database!B5:B50<>0),0),0)+1)
```

Comment: You simply are AWESOME! Thanks a lot Rachel.